# Are the Linux Mint commands the same for Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kali-linux

I want to use Linux. And at first I wanted **Kali Linux**, but it's a bit complicated for me so. I found out that **Linux Mint** is suitable for beginners. But after some experience in Linux I want to use **Kali Linux**. And I wanted to ask **what is the difference between the Linux Mint and Kali Linux commands?** Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just starting with Linux the only differences you'll notice are:

- The software that is installed by default (but you can change that on both of them)
- The default config settings (And you can also change this on both of them)
- The contents of the repo's (And again: adjustable...)

You will only notice (the more subtle) differences once you have more experience.

The following is probably worth mentioning: The last couple of years everyone that doesn't have that much of experience with Linux but wants to become a pentester (or a blackhat) thinks it's a good idea to use Kali.

Kali has indeed a lot of things builtin that will make pentesting less work for you which makes it a really good distro for a pentester. But that doesn't mean that using Kali makes you a pentester.

Pretty much every Linux distro can be configured in such a way that it's useful for pretty much every purpose. A pentester will just usually use Kali because he has to spend less time with configuration and, more important, he knows how to use it.

In other words: Don't worry about the car if you can't drive yet. Once you can do everything you want in Mint then it's time to switch to Kali

Comment: It's *never* time to switch to Kali. Even the people who *make* Kali keep telling people that its purpose is to be a pentesting aid, not a full on desktop OS.

Comment: I cannot agree more, every time i read comments on articles mentioning Kali the first things I think about is: script kiddie

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the commands for the different utilities and programs installed on the system, then yes - they are generally the same (for most system utilities nonetheless).

Both systems are GNU/Linux, and thus uses the GNU Coreutils as well as other GNU utilities either pre-installed or installable afterwards, and these are mostly POSIX compliant.

Also, both systems:

- Are based on Debian, which means they use the same packaging system (dpkg/apt).
- Use systemd as init, system and service manager

But still, there can be differences in which subsystems each distro uses as default, as well as possible differences in the versions of programs you install yourself.

This can lead to different commands on the different systems - but again, generally it should be similar under most circumstances. And any differences you might encounter along the way will probably be documented anyway.